# Is the Atom processor like the Pentium 3 (in performance)?

Tags: performance

Is the Intel Atom N280 (1.66 GHz) like the Pentium 3 (regarding the performance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More like a Pentium 4 Northwood 2.4 GHz.

feel free to browse the **[GeekBench Result Browser](http://browse.geekbench.ca/)**.

Answer (score 1):

It's only slightly faster than the 900mhz Celerons that the very first Eee PCs used.

Comment: fortunately, speed isn't the only factor in how well a CPU performs.

Comment: What do you mean?  In the benchmarks I've seen, the difference is really small.  The  main advantage to the Atom is that it uses less power.

Comment: not in every aspect though, i.e. when it comes to multimedia applications such as flash and HD video, the Celerons (and other processors supporting out-of-order execution) are running circles around the 'in-order' Atom CPUs.

Comment: can i get any free tool for make benchmark on my computer and compare with others computers ?

Comment: @Gold - just get GeekBench (link in my answer), works portable, just copy the install folder to a USB stick and run on other computers, you can also check their result browser for comparisons with similar specced systems.